# Where to replace example schema?

Tags: search, solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7x and want to use SOLR search. I created a core using SOLR Admin UI but getting an error of "unsupported schema". please see screenshots.. I am totally new to SOLR and TYPO3, please help.. [Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVIA8.png),

[Screenshot of core in SOLR Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLGS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Solr layout is usually a home that contains **solr.xml** file and under that one or more collection/core directories, each containing **core.properties** file.

In your Solr screenshot, instanceDir is that collection/core location and it is **/var/solr/data/core_en**. The **schema.xml** and **solrconfig.xml** then live under the **conf** directory within that.

Notice that **schema.xml** would most likely be renamed **managed-schema** on the first run (at least with default **solrconfig.xml**). When you are copying your configs over, make sure to remove old **managed-schema** as well.

Now, one complication is that your Typo3 seems to be looking for it under **/solr/core_en**, which is not the same path as **/var/solr/data/core_en**. I would double check what you have in **/solr/core_en** as well, perhaps you have two conflicting installation or similar.

After you replace the configs, restart Solr or - at least - reload the core in Admin UI's core screen.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. There was no problem with the paths. When i was making the **core**, I moved **conf** folder from **/typo3conf/ext/solr/Resources/Private/Solr/configsets/ext_solr_6_1_0** to **/var/solr/data/core_en** but forgot to move **typo3lib** folder. It worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for your reply. There was no problem with the paths. When i was making the **core**, I moved **conf** folder from **/typo3conf/ext/solr/Resources/Private/Solr/configsets/ext_solr_6_1_0** to **/var/solr/data/core_en** but forgot to move **typo3lib** folder. It worked now. but search is still not working. Whenever i search somthing it says "**Nothing found for "here is the term I search".** "  . In the next step when i index in **search** module, It gives me "**Manual Indexing
An error occurred while indexing manual from the backend**". [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhYm4.png), and when I click **show error** it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr7HC.png).
I'm taking help from docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/Backend/ConnectionManager.html
I appreciate your help.